# Renaming variables (objects, functions, procedures, etc.)

Tags: vba, rename

as far as I know, I have to rename variables used in my VBA code "manually" using the search/replace function in the VBA editor (at least if I don't use an add-on like V-Tools, Speed Ferret, Rubberduck, etc.). "Replace all", which would be quick, might give you unwanted results in some cases. So you have to go through each instance manually always reorienting yourself where the search function jumped to etc.

So my question is: is there another, less time consuming, way? Maybe without the search&replace? Or maybe there an easy to remember pattern how to name a variable (object, function, procedure, etc.) so you are sure that the "replace all" option won't give you any unwanted results?

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you use `Option Explicit`. When you do that, you can be slightly less careful while renaming - compiling your code will make sure that you didn't miss any variable names.

Second - use a good text editor to do your replace and create good regexes to identify your names. Expressions that make sure that you don't have the name as a part of another name.

**Update after comment**
Here's a little snippet to help you with export (and/or code analysis directly in VBE):

```
Sub AllCode()
    Dim Component As Object
    For Each Component In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
        With Component.CodeModule
            For i = 1 To .CountOfDeclarationLines
                Debug.Print .Lines(i, 1)
            Next i
            For i = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1 To .CountOfLines
                Debug.Print .Lines(i, 1)
            Next i
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for you're suggestions. So far I don't see how "Option Explicit" or regular expressions in an external editor will give me a "foolproof" way to use "replace all". Also another problem is: how do you get the code into a external text editor. Copy&Paste is not an option for complex code that's spread over several "countless" modules, too time consuming.

Comment: Nope, nothing foolproof here. I gave some newbie tips here, but you seem to need something else.

Comment: Thanks anyway. So far the best idea seems to be to use regular expressions. Any suggestion on how to "export/import" all the VBA-Code at once into an external editor or is the only way to do it modul by modul? I never tried using an Addon to implement regular expressions into the VBA-Editor, that might be a solution as well.

Comment: Update added above

Comment: nice idea, thanks...  never played around with those objects yet. Instead of creating an output into the "immediate window" I would create a text file so I can either create a nice dump with all my VBA code in all modules or create an individual file for each object. Through the VBComponents Collection you should be able to import them as well - I think... although I haven't tried this yet...

Comment: seems noone had a better answer, it's not the solution I'm looking for, but I'll upvote it, so you get some credit! :)